# How do I reduce the space in the last container?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I'm utilizing Highcharts with containers 2, 3, and 4. Following container 4, there's text marked as ABCD. I'm attempting to minimize the gap between container 4 and the ABCD text. Despite various attempts, I haven't been successful in achieving this.

Here is my code:

```js
function generateChart(containerId, titleText, responses, data) {
    Highcharts.chart(containerId, {
        title: {
            text: titleText,
            align: 'center',
            style: {
                color: '#333333',
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            marginTop: -90,
            events: {
                load: function() {
                    var chart = this,
                        centerX = chart.plotWidth / 2.1,
                        centerY = chart.plotHeight / 3.2,
                        innerSize = '38%',
                        titleText = responses + '<br>Responses';

                    chart.renderer.text(titleText, centerX, centerY)
                        .css({
                            color: '#333333',
                            fontSize: '11px',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        })
                        .add();
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: '38%',
                size: '42%'
            },
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                showInLegend: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: [{
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: 20
                }, {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: -30,
                    format: '{point.percentage:.1f}%',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '0.7em',
                        textOutline: 'none'
                        
                    },
                    filter: {
                        operator: '>',
                        property: 'percentage',
                        value: 10
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
colors: ['#203864', '#b7cbee', '#f8ce04', '#b6992d'],
legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            symbolWidth: 10
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Percentage',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: data
        }]
    });
}

// Generate charts
generateChart('container2', 'Do you like sdd  df gf f gf  fh g h g  j hjhjh j j j jh  gjh j j hj fh g h g  j hjhjh j j j jh  gjh j j fh g h g  j hjhjh j j j jh  gjh j j fh g h g  j hjhjh j j j jh  gjh j j fh g h g  j hjhjh j j j jh  gjh j j?', 549, [
    { name: 'Some of the time', y: 34 },
    { name: 'Never', y: 31 },
    { name: 'Most of the time', y: 35 }
]);

generateChart('container3', 'Do you fdfdfdfg fg h ghg h gfh ghg  jh jh j gh jhj h j hjjhjh?', 549, [
    { name: 'Some of the time', y: 67 },
    { name: 'Most of the time', y: 33 }
]);

generateChart('container4', 'fdfdfdfg fg h ghg h gfh ghg  jh jh j gh jhj h j hjjhjh fdfdfdfg fg h ghg h gfh ghg  jh jh j gh jhj h j hjjhjh.', 543, [
    { name: 'Some of the time', y: 55 },
    { name: 'Never', y: 15 },
    { name: 'Most of the time', y: 25 },
    { name: 'All the time', y: 5 }
]);
```

```css
 
      #container3 {
        margin-top: -40px; /* Adjust the value as needed */
    }
#container4 {
        margin-top: -90px; /* Adjust the value as needed */
        
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="containerall" style=" border: 1px solid lightgray; margin-top: 20px;">
<div id="container2"></div>

<div id="container3"></div>

<div id="container4"></div>
</div>
ABCD
```

Comment: If you're happy enough with how those `/* Adjust the value as needed */` "magic numbers" work out, then you could add a negative `margin-bottom` as well for the last container. Only since the containers have white background and overlap each other, you would need to modify their z-index as well, so that the `ABCD` text doesn't get overlapped. `position: relative; z-index: -1;` for _all_ of them, appears to do the trick.

Comment: You can also set marginBottom straight in the chart options: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginBottom